# Changing the active cell

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2007

I was looking to create a program that examined a column of text in excel and extracted the first line that contained currency. The currency was in Canadian dollars and is formatted in "C $##.##" with no known upper bound but unlikely to reach 10,000 dollars. I was hoping to do this operation 500 times, and save the results in a Master sheet.

I am new to VBA in excel and would appreciate any help on the following code. The problem I am running into is an inability to change active sheet. The script returns #Value! and doesn't get past the line 'SaSh.Range("A1").Select'.

```
Option Explicit
Public NewValue As Integer 'Amount of Money current item is being sold for

Function PriceOfGoods(SaleString As String)

    Dim SaleSheet As Worksheet

    Set SaleSheet = Worksheets(SaleString)

    NewValue = -1

    Call PriceSearch(SaleSheet)

    PriceOfGoods = NewValue

End Function

Public Sub PriceSearch(SaSh As Worksheet)

    Dim StartNumber As Integer
    Dim EndNumber As Integer
    Dim CurrentCell As String

    EndNumber = 1000

    'Activating the Query Sheet and starting search at the top left corner of the sheet
    SaSh.Range("A1").Select

    'Keep searching the A column until you come across the Canadian Currency post
     For StartNumber = 1 To EndNumber

        CurrentCell = ActiveCell.Value

        'Checking to see if the current cell is Canadian Currency
        If WorksheetFunction.IsNumber(CurrencyValuation(CurrentCell)) Then

            NewValue = CurrencyValuation(ActiveCell.Value)
            Exit For

        End If

        'Continue search in the next row
        ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select

    Next StartNumber

End Sub

Function CurrencyValuation(CurrencyInput As String)

Dim NewCurrency As Integer

NewCurrency = WorksheetFunction.Substitute(CurrencyInput, "C", "")

CurrencyValuation = NewCurrency

End Function
```

Comment: Have you looked at any potential problems with SaSh when you pass it into the PriceSearch Function?

Comment: A function called from a worksheet cell is restricted in what it can do:  https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/170787   You can rewrite your `PriceSearch` sub to avoid using `ActiveCell` and `Select`

Comment: Try to be more specific.  i.e. YourWorkbook.YourWorksheet.Range("A1").Select

Comment: `Select` and `ActiveSheet/Cell` are going to cause headaches. Avoid! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba-macros

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The comments made by @Paradox and @Tim are all valid.

To specifically answer your question, you cannot change the `ActiveCell` from code but instead use the `Range` or `Cells` to set a reference to the range:

```
Public Sub PriceSearch(SaSh As Worksheet)

    Dim StartNumber As Integer
    Dim EndNumber As Integer
    Dim CellToCheck As Range

    EndNumber = 1000

    'Search the Query Sheet and starting search at the top left corner of the sheet
    'Keep searching the A column until you come across the Canadian Currency post
     For StartNumber = 1 To EndNumber

        Set CellToCheck = SaSh.Cells(RowIndex:=StartNumber, ColumnIndex:=1)

        'Checking to see if the current cell is Canadian Currency
        If WorksheetFunction.IsNumber(CurrencyValuation(CellToCheck.Value)) Then
            NewValue = CurrencyValuation(CellToCheck.Value)
            Exit For
        End If
    Next StartNumber

End Sub
```